# has_one nested association nullifies foreign key on edit route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, has-one

I am building a nested form in ruby on rails.

The addition of a nested `has_one` association works fine. However, when I load the edit page, the foreign key `company_id` of the nested association is nullified.

I have tried `update_only: true` in `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and including :id in strong params as suggested in other similar answered questions on stackoverflow but nothing works for me.

Could anyone tell me what is actually causing the nested association to update and nullify its foreign key itself? My codes are as shown below. Thanks!

```
# company.rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :mission
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :mission, update_only: true
end

# mission.rb
class Mission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company, optional: true
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
end

# companies_controller.rb
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    @company.build_mission if @company.build_mission.nil?
  end

  def update
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    @company.assign_attributes(company_params)
    if @company.valid?
      @company.save
      redirect_to companies_path
    end
  end

  private

  def company_params
    params.require(:company).permit(mission_attributes: [:id, :description, :_destroy])
  end
end

# edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @company, :url => company_path(@company), :html => {class: 'ui form', method: :put} do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :mission do |mission| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= mission.label :mission %>
      <%= mission.text_field :description %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit => "", class: "ui button" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I manage to solve the problem after a good sleep. Turns out i just have to play around with the if else condition at the companies controller level. The edit method should be amended to such:-

```
def edit
  @company = Company.find(params[:id])
  if @company.mission
  else
    @company.build_mission
  end
end
```